# How to retrieve data for last_transaction from more than 6 months ago using python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I tried to get for the last 6 months, here's the code

```
df_copy['last_transaction'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_transaction'])
df_copy.resample('6M', on='last_transaction').sum().reset_index()
```

am i right?
how to retrieve data for last_transaction from more than 6 months ago using python? I expect the output to be the data from last transaction that is more than 6 months ago

Comment: The resampling is done every 6 months, can you please paste an example and expected output of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your are looking for, but the following code will retrieve the transaction that happened before (today - 6 months)

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

df_copy['last_transaction'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_transaction'])
months_6_ago = pd.to_datetime('today') - DateOffset(months=6)
df_copy[df_copy.last_transaction < months_6_ago]
```